# Sense for splitting shipping text into title and method name

Tags: magento2, shipping-methods

For Shipping "table rate" I have to define a title and the method name. Why are there two fields available? I need only one text for checkout/cart like "depends on balance". 
I try to find a sense for splitting this into two fields or good examples and I try to avoid customizing the code of my installation for this.